# ASP.NET Core session is null after making call request from Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, session-state

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API as back-end and Angular app as front-end. Part of my login process I set user-detail to ASP.NET Core session to be able to check if the session is expired or not using attribute approach (see code below), but as soon as I make any other api request (except login) the session is null (btw the flow works when I use postman).

I read lots of post people said session is stateless and does not not support cross domain, that's why I also used dev-proxy approach to make sure I pass the same httprequest to back-end but still no luck, can you please help!

Here is my code :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
             {
                 options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             })
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", x =>
             {
                  x.SaveToken = true;
                  x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                  x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                         {
                              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecretKey"))),
                              ValidateIssuer = true,
                              ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Token:Issuer"),
                              ValidateAudience = true,
                              ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Token:Audience"),
                              ValidateLifetime = true,
                              ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                              RequireExpirationTime = true,
                         };
             })
            .AddCookie("MyCookiAuth" , option =>
                {
                    option.Cookie.Name = "MyCookiAuth";
                    option.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    option.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
                });

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(option =>
       {
           option.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
           option.Cookie.Name = "Survey-Service";
           option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
           option.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
           option.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
       });
        
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    // global cors policy
    app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
            .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

This is my code to check the session:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class SecuredAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public SecuredAttribute()
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // it isn't needed to set unauthorized result 
            // as the base class already requires the user to be authenticated
            // this also makes redirect to a login page work properly
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        var isAuthorized = SC.SessionExtensions.GetObject<CurrentUserDTO>(context.HttpContext.Session, saasberry_core.Constraints.USER_DETAIL) != null;
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Angular side:
Proxy config json file:

```
{
"/api": {
  "target": "https://localhost:XXXXX/",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
}
```

}

Service class:

```
  public get<E>(url: string, options?, mapper?): Observable<E> {
return this.httpClient
  .get(url)
  .pipe(
    map(json => {
      return mapper ? mapper(json) : json;
    }),
    catchError((errorRes: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (errorRes.error['dataexception']!=null && errorRes.error['dataexception']['data'] != null) {
        var listofExceptions = Object.values(errorRes.error['dataexception']['data']);
        if (listofExceptions.length > 0) {
          listofExceptions.forEach(element => {
            this.extension.showNotification(ColorState.error, element);
          });
        }
      }
      else if (errorRes != null && errorRes.error != null && errorRes.error['message'] != null) {
        this.extension.showNotification(ColorState.error, errorRes.error['message']);
      }
      else {
        this.extension.showNotification(ColorState.error, this.errorMessage);
      }
      if (errorRes.status === 500 && errorRes.error !== null && errorRes.error.code === 401) {
        return;
      }
      return throwError(errorRes.error || 'Server error');
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      // hide loading spinner
    })
  );
```

}

Comment: How is `this.httpClient` in your TypeScript code configured? You do know that the Bearer token has nothing to do with your session cookie? You don't need bearer-tokens/JWT at all if you're using a same-origin SPA: just use session cookies.

Comment: I use JWT token as I have token microservice to generate token for my api gateway part, I know jt token has nothing to do with session, but my question is why session part is not working after any call request ? here is my interceptor for httpclient
 const newRequest = request.clone({
          withCredentials : true ,
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });

Comment: "but my question is why session part is not working after any call request " - because you probably aren't setting cookies on your Angular's `httpClient`. Your ASP.NET Session cookie is configured with `option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;` which means you cannot set it from TypeScript, so you need to instruct the browser to re-use the same cookies (both ASP.NET Core's auth cookie *and* its session cookie) **and** the bearer-token. That said, In think your application's design needs rethinking **because a web-service should not require cookies to operate**.

Comment: the funny part is it even does not create any cookies in browser , would you be a bit more specific about the changes ? I can tell you how I did envision :
- service 1 (api)
- token service (api)
- api-gate-way
- angular app
the angular app make call via api-gateway and it does re-direct to the actual api, at the first time the app generate a token and store it in LS, but i need to know if the session is expired or not then kick the user out and redirect the site to login page,that's why i check if session is still valid or not, what changes is required to make it work based on current

Comment: That's too broad a question for me to answer. Just don't use Session in your controllers that handle AJAX/web-service requests made from Angular **or** change your web-service to stop using Bearer tokens (JWT, etc) and instead use the same authX code that ASP.NET already uses for normal page requests.

Comment: As of 2021, it is impossible to verify OIDC session state (this is _completely unrelated_ to ASP.NET `Session`, btw) in cross-origin and cross-domain scenarios, this is why SPAs using OIDC's `implicit` flow don't work anymore - so you might-as-well just use _only_ normal ASP.NET Core AuthX, that way you keep things much simpler. Read this: https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/